# Apache + Rails: How I change my SSL port from 443 to 8079?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I'm currently in the process of trying to change my Rails app to use port 8443 for SSL (or 8079 if 8443 is used) instead of 443. This is my `ports.conf` file:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    #NameVirtualHost *:443
    NameVirtualHost *:8079
    Listen 80

    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
        # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
        # to <VirtualHost *:443>
        # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
        # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
        #Listen 443
        Listen 8079
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        #Listen 443
        Listen 8079
    </IfModule>
```

In my virtual hosts file I have: `<VirtualHost *:8079>` but it's not working. Firefox says: `Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at mysite.com` when I try to go on the https://mysite.com/check_out/shopping_cart

How would I change the SSL port from 443 to something else? Is there more than just the apache config? Passenger perhaps? Rails? I already updated my firewall to accept connections through those ports, but it isn't working.

Comment: Why are you trying to change the port? Your explanation seems to suggest you really do _not_ want to change the port.

Answer (score 0):

Your server config appears correct. When using a non-standard port, you have to specify the port number in your client-side URL, like this: `https://mysite.com:8079/check_out/shopping_cart`.